# Changing object position on one key frame changes the rest of the frames as well

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging

Basically, I have my human model all rigged up, and have created two different keyframes.
The first key frame, the foot is on the ground while the 2nd, it's rotated a bit up.
The problem is, when I rotate the foot on Frame number 1, it also changes it on frame
number 2... Now, on frame number 2, the foot is tilted vertically instead of flat on the
grid surface. If i try to change it on frame 2, it ruins it on frame 1 since it doesn't really copy it, but instead it somehow adds extra changes.

Is there a way to to somehow make it not copy rotates etc to other frames?

Comment: Could you post a blend file ?

Comment: please only post your question, do not place "ads" for other things like your skype list.

Comment: Did you actually make a key-frame for the selected joint before moving to the next frame? (With the hotkey 'i' by default)

Answer (score 1):

If you have placed a keyframe only on the "Feet" Bone try to add the frame one and two for the entire leg (Loc,Rot) it should work. If not, try to check the amount of rotation the bone deal with between these two frames, if it's too high it could cause bad moves between frames !